# Unable to download file from remote sftp server to local directory using spring integration without polling using spring inbound channel adapter

Tags: spring-integration

My requirement is to download a particular file with .json extension from a dynamic path in the remote sftp server only when a user clicks a particular button in GUI i.e in short file needs to be downloaded only during a rest service call to a remote server.The remote directory path will be passed as a parameter to the service call.I need to do it using spring integration module in a spring boot project using java configurations.I am new to spring integration.Can anyone please help me on the same?

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of task you should use an `SftpOutboundGateway` with the `Command.GET`.

See Documentation on the matter: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/sftp.html#_using_the_literal_get_literal_command_2

The `expression` option of the `SftpOutboundGateway` must evaluates to the remote path including file name. It can be simply `expresion="payload"` or refer to any header or can be evaluated against any other beans in the application context.

You can get some ideas from the existing SFTP sample: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/sftp